# how to use double group by and sum statements together in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use query below but it is giving an error

```
SELECT s.LOCAL_CODE,substr(p.ACCOUNT_CREDIT,-3),(p.SUMMA/100) as profit
        FROM OPERATIONS s INNER JOIN LEADS p ON s.PAY_ID = p.PAY_ID
            WHERE s.date_paid >= TO_DATE('03.12.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
               AND s.date_paid < TO_DATE('03.12.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
               AND state = 'T'
               AND s.filial_code = '006789'
               AND SUBSTR(p.ACCOUNT_CREDIT, 1, 5) = '765294'
    GROUP BY s.LOCAL_CODE,substr(p.ACCOUNT_CREDIT,-3);
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59591062/edit) to include the entire error message that you are getting. Also, an explanation of what you are trying to do, along with sample data and expected results, would make your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `LEADS.SUMMA` has expected value then you don't need `Group By` clause, else if you use `Group By` then all not grouped fields can be used only as arguments of aggregate functions:

```
SELECT s.LOCAL_CODE
, Substr(p.ACCOUNT_CREDIT, -3)
, Sum(p.SUMMA)/100 as profit
FROM OPERATIONS s 
INNER JOIN LEADS p ON s.PAY_ID = p.PAY_ID
WHERE s.date_paid >= TO_DATE('03.12.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
AND s.date_paid < TO_DATE('03.12.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND state = 'T'
AND s.filial_code = '006789'
AND SUBSTR(p.ACCOUNT_CREDIT, 1, 5) = '765294'
GROUP BY s.LOCAL_CODE
, substr(p.ACCOUNT_CREDIT, -3);
```